# How can I obtain a list of cameras available in my PC and open a specific camera?

Tags: c++, opencv

recently I use C++ and opencv to make a program dealing with the camera. How can I find out the cameras available in my PC and open a specific camera?

Comment: Are you trying to read a number presented to the camera using OCR?

Comment: `cvCaptureFromCAM` takes index of the camera you want to work with.

Comment: what is OCR? can you tell me more detail?

Comment: it seems that cvCaptureFromCAM can not open the specified camera!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Windows I believe you can open a camera selection screen by using `cvCaptureFromCam(-1)` See the [reference](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#capturefromcam) for more information